# My django query is very slow in givig me data on terminal

Tags: python, django

I have a users table which has 3 types of users Student, Faculty and Club and I have a university table.
What I want is how many users are there in the specific university.
I am getting my desired output but the output is very slow.I have 90k users and the output it is generating it takes minutes to produce results.

My user model:-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cms.models.masterUserTypes import MasterUserTypes
from cms.models.universities import Universities
from cms.models.departments import MasterDepartments



# WE ARE AT MODELS/APPUSERS

requestChoice = (
    ('male', 'male'),
    ('female', 'female'),
    )


class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    userTypeId = models.ForeignKey(MasterUserTypes, db_column="userTypeId")
    universityId = models.ForeignKey(Universities, db_column="universityId")  
    departmentId = models.ForeignKey(MasterDepartments , db_column="departmentId",help_text="")  
    name = models.CharField(db_column="name",max_length=255,help_text="")
    username = models.CharField(db_column="username",unique=True, max_length=255,help_text="")
    email = models.CharField(db_column="email",unique=True, max_length=255,help_text="")
    password = models.CharField(db_column="password",max_length=255,help_text="")
    bio = models.TextField(db_column="bio",max_length=500,help_text="")
    gender = models.CharField(db_column="gender",max_length=6, choices=requestChoice,help_text="")
    mobileNo = models.CharField(db_column='mobileNo', max_length=16,help_text="")  
    dob = models.DateField(db_column="dob",help_text="")
    major = models.CharField(db_column="major",max_length=255,help_text="")
    graduationYear = models.IntegerField(db_column='graduationYear',max_length=11,help_text="")  
    canAddNews = models.BooleanField(db_column='canAddNews',default=False,help_text="")  
    receivePrivateMsgNotification = models.BooleanField(db_column='receivePrivateMsgNotification',default=True ,help_text="")  
    receivePrivateMsg = models.BooleanField(db_column='receivePrivateMsg',default=True ,help_text="")
    receiveCommentNotification = models.BooleanField(db_column='receiveCommentNotification',default=True ,help_text="")  
    receiveLikeNotification = models.BooleanField(db_column='receiveLikeNotification',default=True ,help_text="")  
    receiveFavoriteFollowNotification = models.BooleanField(db_column='receiveFavoriteFollowNotification',default=True ,help_text="")  
    receiveNewPostNotification = models.BooleanField(db_column='receiveNewPostNotification',default=True ,help_text="")  
    allowInPopularList = models.BooleanField(db_column='allowInPopularList',default=True ,help_text="")  
    xmppResponse = models.TextField(db_column='xmppResponse',help_text="")  
    xmppDatetime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='xmppDatetime', help_text="")  
    status = models.BooleanField(db_column="status", default=False, help_text="")
    deactivatedByAdmin = models.BooleanField(db_column="deactivatedByAdmin", default=False, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    modifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='modifiedAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    updatedBy = models.ForeignKey(User,db_column="updatedBy",help_text="Logged in user updated by ......")
    lastPasswordReset = models.DateTimeField(db_column='lastPasswordReset',help_text="")
    authorities = models.CharField(db_column="departmentId",max_length=255,help_text="")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'
```

the query i am using which is producing the desired output but too sloq is:-

```
universities = Universities.objects.using('cms').all()
    for item in universities:
        studentcount = Users.objects.using('cms').filter(universityId=item.id,userTypeId=2).count()
        facultyCount = Users.objects.using('cms').filter(universityId=item.id,userTypeId=1).count()
        clubCount = Users.objects.using('cms').filter(universityId=item.id,userTypeId=3).count()
        totalcount = Users.objects.using('cms').filter(universityId=item.id).count()
        print studentcount,facultyCount,clubCount,totalcount
        print item.name
```

Comment: please use Django's built-in User model

Comment: You should look at the queries that are running (e.g. using Django debug toolbar). If there are queries that are running slowly, then you might be able to add indexes to speed them up. If the problem is simply that you have many queries, then using `annotate` as Iain suggests should help.

Answer (score 2):

You should use annotate to get the counts for each university and conditional expressions to get the counts based on conditions [(docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)

```
Universities.objects.using('cms').annotate(
    studentcount=Sum(Case(When(users_set__userTypeId=2, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())),
    facultyCount =Sum(Case(When(users_set__userTypeId=1, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())),
    clubCount=Sum(Case(When(users_set__userTypeId=3, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())),
    totalcount=Count('users_set'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, an obvious optimization. In the loop, you're doing essentially the same query four times: thrice filtering for different `userTypeId`, and once without one. You can do this in a single `COUNT(*) ... GROUP BY userTypeId` query.

```
...
# Here, we're building a dict {userTypeId: count}
# by counting PKs over each userTypeId
qs = Users.objects.using('cms').filter(universityId=item.id)
counts = {
    x["userTypeId"]: x["cnt"]
    for x in qs.values('userTypeId').annotate(cnt=Count('pk'))
}

student_count = counts.get(2, 0)
faculty_count = counts.get(1, 0)
club_count = count.get(3, 0)
total_count = sum(count.values())  # Assuming there may be other userTypeIds
...
```

However, you're still doing 1+n queries, where n is number of universities you have in the database. This is fine if the number is low, but if it's high you need further aggregation, joining `Universities` and `Users`. A first draft I came with is something like this:

```
# Assuming University.name is unique, otherwise you'll need to use IDs
# to distinguish between different projects, instead of names.
qs = Users.objects.using('cms').values('userTypeId', 'university__name')\
    .annotate(cnt=Count('pk').order_by('university__name')
for name, group in itertools.groupby(qs, lambda x: x["university__name"]):
    print("University: %s" % name)
    cnts = {g["userTypeId"]: g["cnt"] for g in group}
    faculty, student, club = cnts.get(1, 0), cnts.get(2, 0), cnts.get(3, 0)
    # NOTE: I'm assuming there are only few (if any) userTypeId values
    #       other than {1,2,3}.
    total = sum(cnts.values())
    print("  Student: %d, faculty: %d, club: %d, total: %d" % (
          student, faculty, club, total))
```

I might've made a typo there, but hope it's correct. In terms of SQL, it should emit a query like

```
SELECT uni.name, usr.userTypeId, COUNT(usr.id)
FROM some_app_universities AS uni
LEFT JOUN some_app_users AS usr ON us.universityId = uni.id
GROUP BY uni.name, usr.userTypeId
ORDER BY uni.name
```

Consider reading documentation on [aggregations and annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/). And be sure to check out raw SQL that Django ORM emits (e.g. use [Django Debug Toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) and analyze how well it works on your database. For example, use `EXPLAIN SELECT` if you're using PostgreSQL. Depending on your dataset, you may benefit from some indexes there (e.g. on `userTypeId` column).

Oh, and on a side note... it's off-topic, but in Python it's a custom to have variables and attributes use `lowercase_with_underscores`. In Django, model class names are usually singular, e.g. `User` and `University`.